# Python How to add nested fields to Yaml file

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I need to modify a YAML file and add several fields.I am using the ruamel.yaml package.

First I load the YAML file:

```
data = yaml.load(file_name)
```

I can easily add new simple fields, like-

```
data['prop1'] = "value1"
```

The problem I face is that I need to add a nested dictionary incorporate with array:

```
prop2:
  prop3:
    - prop4:
        prop5:  "Some title" 
        prop6:  "Some more data"
```

I tried to define-

```
record_to_add = dict(prop2 = dict(prop3 = ['prop4']))
```

This is working, but when I try to add beneath it prop5 it fails-

```
record_to_add = dict(prop2 = dict(prop3 = ['prop4'= dict(prop5 = "Value")]))
```

I get

> SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By indenting a line four spaces (select lines then press Ctrl+K) you get a more readable question. Your YAML was not valid.

Comment: Try this. 'record_to_add = dict(prop2 = dict(prop3 = [dict(prop4 = dict(prop5 = "Value"))]))'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its because of having ['prop4'= <> ].Instead `record_to_add = dict(prop2 = dict(prop3 = [dict(prop4 = dict(prop5 = "Value"))]))` should work.

Another alternate would be,

```
import yaml

data = {
     "prop1": {
         "prop3":
             [{ "prop4":
                   {
                       "prop5": "some title",
                       "prop6": "some more data"
                   }
             }]
     }
 }

with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(data, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

Comment: Yep- this worked!!! now I can proceed

Answer (score 1):

The problem has little to do with `ruamel.yaml`. This:

```
['prop4'= dict(prop5 = "Value")]
```

is invalid Python as a list (`[ ]`) expects comma separated values. You would need to use something like:

```
record_to_add = dict(prop2 = dict(prop3 = dict(prop4= [dict(prop5 = "Some title"), dict(prop6='Some more data'),])))
```

As your program is incomplete I am not sure if you are using the old API or not. Make sure to use

```
import ruamel.yaml
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
```

and **not**

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using the correct ruamel.yaml, not the old

Comment: Just wanted to be sure, as sometimes people start using `ruamel.yaml` looking at an out-of-date example.